# JS só funciona atualizando a página

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails4

Clico no botão:

```
<td><%= link_to 'simulacao', simulacao_path(simulado) %></td>
```

na pagina simulacao/id tem outro botao que requisita o js, mas só funciona se eu atualizar a pagina

```
<%= form_tag('/correcao', method: :get, remote: true) %>

<%= button_tag 'Corrigir', class:'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
```

routes:

```
get 'simulacao/:id' => 'simulados#simulacao', as: 'simulacao'
get '/correcao' => 'simulados#correcao'
```

acabei de nota que mesmo clicando em qualquer link o botao fica sem função:

```
<a href="#">nao faz nada</a>
```

uma luz? =D

Comment: Algum erro no console do js?

Comment: Não, ele simplesmente não tem ação

Comment: Tem como mostrar como fica o Html do form? e o log do console, só pra gente poder dar uma diagnosticada?

Comment: Resolvido! um simples form fechado no lugar errado, já tive muitos problemas para carregar JS por isso o trauma. obrigado por ajudar =D